# How can I retrieve image error code using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, onerror

I am changing the `src` attribute of an image element. If there's an error I want to know the error status code.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to make an attempt and show some code.

Comment: onerror does not have the details so you would have to make a fetch call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt [this source example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) on mdn web docs. If you change the `src` attribute programmatically and need to check first if it gives an error code, it could do the job. Here a draft, I hope this is going to help you.

```js
let changesrc = (newsrc) => {
  const myImage = document.getElementById('testimg');
  const myRequest = new Request(newsrc);

  fetch(myRequest).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.status);
    if(response.status == "200") {
      response.blob().then((myBlob) => {
        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        myImage.src = objectURL;
      });
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<button onclick="changesrc('https://picsum.photos/200');">test ok</button>
<button onclick="changesrc('https://picsum.photos/noway');">test not ok</button>
<img id='testimg' src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```

Comment: had to change a bit, but your code gave a clear idea. thanks, god bless you

Comment: @shasabbir, I'm glad it helped you :) Happy coding sessions !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image API in Javascript, for know when image load fail:

```
function mountImage(src) {
  const img = new Image();
  
  img.src = src;

  img.onload = () => {
    // image loaded
  }

  img.onerror = () => {
     // image fail load
  }



}
```

Comment: Initially I followed this approach but with this approach you can only handle error generally. I need some thing which will give error code and I will handle according to error code specifically. btw thanks, really appreciate it.